# I want to start studying the field of machine translation

Tags: machine-learning, python, nlp, machine-translation

I've studied Japanese language and literature and passed some linguistic courses and now as for my masters, I want to study natural language processing and especially machine translation. so I tried taking some data science courses online and I'm now a little bit familiar with data science but I know literally nothing about machine translation.
so, long story short, I need to write a proposal in the machine translation field (university requirements) but I don't know where to start reading about machine translation. I tried to read some essays but the level was too high for me, I didn't understand a single thing.
I'd be so thankful if you could guide me through this journey.
thank you ^__^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you certainly know, Machine Translation (MT) is a very challenging and useful task in the domain of Natural Language Processing (NLP). As such it is a very specialized research domain but also a very active area of research, and a very competitive one (in particular due to commercial applications, obviously).

So there's a massive amount of research being done and a massive amount of resources, but in order to gain real expertise in MT one needs to acquire quite a lot of background knowledge. Let's be clear: a beginner level in data science is not sufficient to understand state of the art MT. Typically one needs not only a good level in statistics and programming, but also knowledge of the recent progress in MT: the old statistical MT approach (e.g. [Moses](http://www.statmt.org/moses/)) has been replaced with  better Neural MT approaches.

A slightly less ambitious objective would be to study the limitations of current MT systems, since this doesn't require understanding how they work. Note that even simply training a state of the art model using existing software is not trivial, and requires quite a lot of computational resources. I'd suggest looking at the resources and papers published at the [Workshop on Machine Translation](http://www.statmt.org/wmt20/) (check also the previous years). Note also that there are many sub-tasks related to MT to look at:

- model design
- evaluation metrics
- building training corpora
- quality estimation
- post-editing

The WMT Shared Tasks offer datasets for these different sub-tasks. Reading the overview paper for a task is a good way to get an idea of what it is and how it's done.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I really appreciate how detailed your answer was. 
I'll try and follow your lead, hope I can overcome this challenge.

Comment: @takeshihatake if possible try to find an advisor who is expert in MT, so that they can help you find a topic which is both interesting and realistic.